# How do I visually see all changes between current commit and a specific commit in history?

Tags: git, github

I want to see all changes done until commit X. I want to see these changes in a visual manner, the same way that github.com shows the updates between each commit. Is it possible to group all the changes that happened since commit X and compare them?

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to do this using a local git client, or in the Github UI?

Comment: Something that works. I just need to see this and I'd rather not have it be on the console since it's not really easy to read from there.

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for a GitHub forum: https://github.community/

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits

Comment: you can run `gitk ...master` or any other `branch`/`commit_hash`, which OS you are using? but this should work in Mac and I think in linux too.

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. How is this different from a diff? Or if you are an Mac or Windows why not use Sourcetree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using GitHub. The following is an example on the [Bootstrap repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap):

1. Find and copy the ID of the commit you are interested in:
   [image: Find and copy the ID of the commit you are interested in]
2. Go to `https://github.com/user/repo/compare`. In this example, [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/compare). Paste the commit ID under "base", and leave "compare" as `master`:
   [image: Go to <code>https://github.com/user/repo/compare</code>]
3. This gives the desired result:
   [image: This gives the desired result]